# How do I add a decimal value to a <div> using the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

It is supposed to add a value of 0.1 every time someone clicks on a button.

I tried to add a value to it:

```
var change = document.getElementById("points");
change = change + 0.1;
```

I was expecting it to change the div value by 0.1 and it did nothing.

Comment: `change` is a `HTMLElement`. It sounds like you want to manipulate h its `innerText` property value.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button and an event handler to change the value

```js
const change = document.getElementById("points");
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", e => {
  // find out the current value and convert it to floating point
  const value = parseFloat(change.textContent);
  // add 0.1, tidy up the value with toFixed and update the output
  change.textContent = (value + 0.1).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<button id="go">Go</button>
<output id="points">0</output>
```